# How Git detect missed "src" or ":dst" from refspec

Tags: git

We know this is the structure of `refspec`:

[+]src:dst

[Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=qIucp61eqAwC&pg=PA202&lpg=PA202&dq=In%20some%20uses,%20the%20source%20ref%20is%20optional;%20in%20others,%20the%20colon%20and%20destination%20ref%20are%20optional.&source=bl&ots=je_LEkVnzD&sig=Z_PJFpq5UjJ9C6PnNCRfxCVeiJE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmpdTtnJ_MAhWC2RoKHf4EAfcQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=In%20some%20uses%2C%20the%20source%20ref%20is%20optional%3B%20in%20others%2C%20the%20colon%20and%20destination%20ref%20are%20optional.&f=false) you can see:

> In some uses, the source ref is optional; in others, the colon and
>   destination ref are optional.

But how git can detect missed "src" or ":dst"? Or how it complete the structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an exercise for you.  Consider the following refspecs:

1. `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`
2. `refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master`
3. `HEAD:branch1`
4. `:branch2`
5. `branch3`

Can you identify which part of 1, 2, and 3 are the `src` and `:dst` parts?  (This should be *very* easy.)

What about #4: one of `src` or `:dst` is missing.  Which one is missing and which one is present?

What about #5: one of `src` or `:dst` is again missing.  Which one is missing and which one is present?

These should also be easy.

#### *After* completing the exercise...

Now that you can easily identify which part is which, we can talk about how these various parts are used.  Note that the treatment of partial refspecs—refspecs that are missing either the `<src>` part or the `:<dst>` part—is different in `git fetch` vs `git push`.

(For that matter, so is the treatment of complete refspecs, except here it is much easier: with `fetch`, the *remote* part is on the left, as the `<src>`, and the `:<dst>` part refers to a reference in your own repository.  With `push`, the left or `<src>` side is your reference and the right or `:<dst>` side is theirs.)

For `git fetch`, a partial refspec is meaningless (is an error) if the `<src>` part is missing.  Only the `:<dst>` part may be omitted.  Omitting the `:<dst>` part tells `git fetch` to skip the update it would normally make that would remember the remote's reference.  That is, a full refspec like `refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master` means that git should read `refs/heads/master` off the remote, and then write whatever it saw into your own copy at `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  Without the `:<dst>` part, git might not write this anywhere.<sup>1</sup>

The `git push` command behaves very differently.  Omitting the `<src>` part, as in `git push origin :branch2`, sends a *deletion* request to the remote.  Omitting the `:<dst>` part makes your `git push` choose some default `:<dst>`.  The exact choice depends on your configuration (and your version of git, since some of the newer configuration controls did not exist in older versions), but the "default default" is to repeat the `<src>` part, so that `git push origin branch3` translates to `git push origin branch3:branch3`.

Note that if you use a short (unqualified with `refs/heads/` or `refs/tags/`) name like `branch3`, git tries to figure out automatically whether this is a branch or tag by poking around in your set of branches and tags.  If you have a tag named `v3.7` and no branch named `v3.7`, git will figure out that `git push origin v3.7` means `git push origin refs/tags/v3.7:refs/tags/v3.7`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Of course, not writing it *anywhere* would be quite useless, but `git fetch` *always* writes *everything* to the special file `FETCH_HEAD`.  Since git 1.8.4, `git fetch` also consults all the `fetch =` refspecs from the config file, so that `refs/remotes/origin/master` typically gets updated anyway.  Choosing unusual refspecs for, or omitting or deleting, the `fetch =` lines can illustrate this, but most of the time, with git 1.8.4 or newer, this particular distinction sort of vanishes.

For example, suppose remote `origin` has branches `alpha`, `beta`, and `master`, where `alpha` has active development "alpha" state code ("we don't necessarily even believe this works, but it has the latest ideas in it"), `beta` has proposed-for-`master` "we believe it works but it's still not well tested" code, and `master` has the tested/supported version that users should generally run.  Meanwhile your `remote.origin.fetch` line is set to the default value of `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.

You decide you want to grab the latest `alpha` so you are about to run `git fetch origin alpha`.  Git will write the SHA-1 for origin's `refs/heads/alpha` to `FETCH_HEAD`, but in git 1.8.4 or newer, it will *also* write this SHA-1 to `refs/remotes/origin/alpha`.  Git will not update `refs/remotes/origin/beta` nor `refs/remotes/origin/master` *even if those are actually the same new SHA-1*.

Then you decide, before you enter the command, that you want to pick up the beta version as well, so you actually enter `git fetch origin alpha beta`.  Git will write the two SHA-1s for origin's `refs/heads/alpha` and `refs/heads/beta` to both `FETCH_HEAD` and their corresponding remote-tracking branches, but will not update `refs/remotes/origin/master`.

If the two updated branches have different SHA-1s, both of which require bringing over new objects, the `fetch` you actually entered will bring over more objects than the `fetch` you were about to enter, since it will have to bring over the objects needed to make the brought-over `beta` valid.

Comment: But it seems `Since git 1.8.4, git fetch also processes all the fetch = refspecs from the config file ...` is not true  if you use a refspec explicitly in command line.

Comment: @hasanghaforian: depends what you interpret "process" to mean.  I should clarify this.  Using `git fetch origin master` *will* update `origin/master`, but not `origin/develop`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Read about it here:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec#Deleting-References

> You can also use the refspec to delete references from the remote server by running something like this:
>
> ```
> $ git push origin :topic
> ```
>
> Because the refspec is `<src>:<dst>`, by leaving off the `<src>` part, this basically says to **make the topic branch on the remote nothing**, which deletes it.

Comment: And what when `:<dst>` is missed?